# Removing specific objects in arrays from references in dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary

**My question :**

I need to know if what i'm doing is the best way, and if it's not, what is?

**The situation :**

I have "Contacts" objects in an array. These contacts must be ordered alphabetically and can have multiple phone numbers. I'm splitting that array into 27 arrays of contacts where each of them reprensents a letter of the alphabet. So i have all my "A" contacts, then "B" and so on.
Also, during the "splitting", I also add a reference of each contact in a dictionary, where the object is the contact, and the key is his phone number.

Because one contact can have X phone numbers, there can be X times the same contact in X different entries in the dictionary. I need that so i can find any contact with any number.

All of the above works like a charm.

Now I need to compare all those numbers from my online database (note: i'm using parse), to see if some of these contacts are already users or not. If they are, they need to be put in a specific section of my tableview. (my tableview is just all the contacts, separated in letter sections, + one "user" section). And the contacts can not appear in the user section AND the letter section. If a contact is a user, he must be separated.

**What i'm asking vs What i'm doing :**

Right now, i'm just re-looping every array and comparing each element to all the users i've found online. This is a lot of looping and looks like a waste of time and resources.

What i would like to do : Somehow cleaning my arrays of the users i've found, considering i have the reference of the contact object in my dictionary.

### **TL;DR:**

My arrays :

users in the first section, then contacts alphabtically

[[user1, user2, user3, ...],[a1,a2,a3,...],[b1,b2,...],...]

My dictionary :

- a1 - phone1
- a1 - phone2
- a1 - phone3
- a2 - phone1
- a3 - phone1
- ...

**The ultimate question :**

I can very easily find the contact object (since i have his number from my online db). If i interact with the a1 from the dictionary, will it also change the a1 in the array of arrays?
More specifically, can i somehow REMOVE IT from the array considering I don't know which one he is in?

Answer (score 0):

> I also add a reference of each contact in a dictionary, where the object is the contact, and the key is his phone number.

You need to be very careful with this approach. It is likely to have collisions. While cell phone numbers are often unique, sometimes they're shared. Home and work numbers are often shared. Phone numbers get reassigned, so your database can wind up with duplicates that way, too. And sometimes people just enter mistaken data. You have to make sure your system behaves reasonably and consistently in those cases. Many behaviors are fine, but "pick one at random" is generally not.

You should think carefully here about what is your model and what is your presentation. One data structure should be the single source of truth. Usually that's going to be your big list of contacts. That has nothing at all to do with how it's displayed. We call this the model. Often it's kept track of as an `NSSet` since order doesn't matter.

Above that you should have a "view model" that deals with grouping and sorting issues. It is not "truth." You should be willing to throw it away anytime the underlying data changes extensively. Its data structures should point to the underlying model, and should be stored in a way that exactly matches what the table view wants. Keeping the model and the view model separate is one of the best ways to keep your complexity under control. Then you know that there is exactly one place that data can change (the model), and everything else just reacts to that.

Regarding your partitioning problem: so you have a list of contacts and you want to separate them into two groups based on whether any of their phone numbers appear in another list. If your total list is only a few dozen entries long, frankly it doesn't matter how you do this. Even O(n^2) is fine for small enough *n*. Focus on making it simple and reliable first, then profile with Instruments to see where the real bottlenecks are.

That said, usually the fastest way to determine set intersection is to sort both sets and walk through them both at the same time. So you'd create a "contacts" array of "phone number + contact pointer" and a "users" array of just phone numbers. Sort them both by phone number. Walk over them, comparing the current element of each list, and then incrementing the index of the smaller one. If no match, put the contact in one list. If a match, put it in the other.

But I'd probably just stick all the phone numbers in a set and use `member:` to look them up. It's just usually easier.